# What causes the error ... ESB section is missing from the configuration source?

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, biztalk, biztalk-2010, esb-toolkit-2.1

We have an issue where connection between the BizTalk servers and the backing SQL Server is lost.
Some of the orchestrations are exposed as WCF end points in IIS

When the SQL connection problem occurs, we get errors ...

```
The ESB section is missing from the configuration source.     
Source: Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.PipelineComponents.ItinerarySelector
```

The only fix seems to be doing an IISRESET, which is a bit heavy handed

Seems the ESB Toolkit uses the Enterprise Library [ConfigurationSource](http://blogs.biztalk360.com/esb-toolkit-2-1-mess-up-enterprise-library-5-0-big-time/)
to read the `esb.config`

But why is the ESB section being lost?

And even better, a real fix for the problem!

Comment: Doing a bit of searching I came across the following blog. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cfde263-e6f6-4ddb-bc98-77a43f85adc7/the-esb-section-is-missing-from-the-configuration-source?forum=biztalkesb   No solution as yet.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Thanks for the response. It's worrying that their solution was also a full IISRESET ... I was hoping we could get away with just recycling the particular app pool. What's worse is the "fixed in next update", but as far as I can see, there haven't been any fixes for the ESB Toolkit.